# Решить задачу, используя 1 массив

Tags: java, arraylist

Привет. Написал небольшую програмку.

**Условие:** "Дан массив размера n. После каждого отрицательного элемента массива вставить элемент с нулевым значением".

Я решил её, используя 2 массива ArrayList. Меня интересует, возможно ли получить решение, используя только 1 массив?

**Код программы:**

```
public class Task_108 {
public void Task108(){

    System.out.println("Input size of array: ");
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int sizeArr = scn.nextInt();
    ArrayList<Integer> ArrIntNum = new ArrayList<>(sizeArr);            // Declare array

    Random rnd = new Random();
    int val;
    // Filling array random elements from -20 to 20
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeArr; i++){
        val = -20 + rnd.nextInt(41);
        ArrIntNum.add(i, val);
    }
    // Output array on the screen
    System.out.println(ArrIntNum.toString());

    ArrayList<Integer> ArrWithZeroAftNegVal = new ArrayList<>();        // Declare once more array

    // Adding zero after every negative number in array ArrIntNum and write in array ArrWithZeroAftNegVal
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeArr; i ++){
        if(ArrIntNum.get(i) < 0) {
            ArrWithZeroAftNegVal.add(ArrIntNum.get(i));
            ArrWithZeroAftNegVal.add(0);
        }
        else
            ArrWithZeroAftNegVal.add(ArrIntNum.get(i));
    }
    // Output edited array on the screen
    System.out.println(ArrWithZeroAftNegVal.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Если под массивом мы подразумеваем только голый массив, то можно, если до создания массива известно кол-во элементов. Если, как в вашем случае, под массивом подразумевается ArrayList, то реализация элементарна.

Comment: Если использовать голый массив с заранее известным размером, то его размер нельзя будет увеличить. Используя обычный массив, эту задачу не решить. Или я не прав?

Comment: @Arthur Вы можете использовать массив изначально удвоенной длины. просто помня сколько на самом деле элементов вам надо. В таком случа двигаясь от последнего объявленного элемента массива к началу сдвигаем все элементы в самый конец, добавляя нули по необходимости. Потом передвигаем все обратно к началу

Answer (score 0):

Вы путаете понятие массива и списка. В вашем примере используется список. У списков есть метод для добавления нового элемента по индексу. Для этого вы можете воспользоваться перегруженным методом `add`:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
numbers.add(1);
numbers.add(2);
numbers.add(3);
numbers.add(4);

// число 0 встанет на место второго элемента в списке
numbers.add(2, 0);

numbers.forEach(System.out::print);
```

Но более красивое решение можно получить с двумя списками:

```
List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
numbers.add(1);
numbers.add(2);
numbers.add(-3);
numbers.add(4);
numbers.add(-2);
numbers.add(5);
numbers.add(4);

numbers = numbers
        .stream()
        .flatMap(number -> number < 0 ? Stream.of(number, 0) : Stream.of(number))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

numbers.forEach(System.out::print);
```